# vertx LoggerHandler not adding logback

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, vert.x

I am trying to use LoggerHandler to log all incoming requests. I am using logback.xml to specify appenders. I am setting system property for logging.

```
System.setProperty("org.vertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name",
            "org.vertx.java.core.logging.impl.SLF4JLogDelegateFactory");
```

Still it is logging everything in console not in file.

Comment: Please refer to vert.x [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vertx/Mh7nIHru1Zk)

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me with Vert.x 3.4.1:

```
    import static io.vertx.core.logging.LoggerFactory.LOGGER_DELEGATE_FACTORY_CLASS_NAME;
    import io.vertx.core.logging.LoggerFactory;

    // ...

    setProperty (LOGGER_DELEGATE_FACTORY_CLASS_NAME, SLF4JLogDelegateFactory.class.getName ());
    LoggerFactory.getLogger (LoggerFactory.class); // Required for Logback to work in Vertx
```

The key is to get a logger, which I guess initializes the Logging subsystem, the class that you use to get a Logger seems irrelevant as I tried with two different ones.

I run these lines as the first ones of the program in production code **and in the tests** to work properly in both contexts.

Comment: Always add imports when answering.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get it to work by setting the VM options as such:

```
-Dvertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name=io.vertx.core.logging.Log4jLogDelegateFactory
```

Then in my log4j.properties, I had to add this:

```
log4j.category.io.vertx = TRACE
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is getting a bit old, but the only way I was able to get the vertx `LoggerHandler` to not use JUL was to call `LoggerFactory.initialise()` after setting the system property as described in the question.

Even better, I set the property in my build.gradle, like so:

```
run {
  systemProperty(
    "vertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name",
    "io.vertx.core.logging.SLF4JLogDelegateFactory"
  )
  args = ['run', mainVerticleName, "--redeploy=$watchForChange", "--launcher-class=$mainClassName", "--on-redeploy=$doOnChange",
          "-Dvertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name=io.vertx.core.logging.SLF4JLogDelegateFactory" ]
}
```

And then at the very top of my `MainVerticle::start` I have:

```
LoggerFactory.initialise()
```

And, boom. Everything is now formatted correctly, including all the startup output.