# Configure logger in vertx 3

Tags: java, logging, vert.x

I am using vertx 3.0 with spring boot. Now I am trying to config logger log levels, using below config:

JVM Arguments:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev 
-Dvertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name=io.vertx.core.logging.SLF4JLogDelegateFactory 
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties
```

logging.properties:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=ERROR
com.sensegrow.level=ERROR
```

JAVA Class:

```
package com.sensegrow.main;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application{

    private static Logger logger ;
    public static JsonObject config;
    private static Vertx vertx;

    // Convenience method so you can run it in your IDE
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
        logger.trace("trace");
        logger.debug("debug");
        logger.info("info");
        logger.warn("warning");
        logger.error("error");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
16:29:58.073 [                main] INFO  - com.sensegrow.main.Application           - info
16:29:58.076 [                main] WARN  - com.sensegrow.main.Application           - warning
16:29:58.076 [                main] ERROR - com.sensegrow.main.Application           - error
```

As log level for package com.sensegrow is error. Why I am getting Info and warn level logs.

Answer (score 2):

So, try this: give ur config file this name:
`vertx-default-jul-logging.properties` and
place it into src/main/resources.

put in that content:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=FINEST

.level=ERROR
com.sensegrow.level=ERROR
```

Run main().
This will work. From that on try to rename it and extend it to your needs. :)

Hope this helps.

PS: till here you dont need any jvm variables. Try this first and then extend it. If then something doens't work and you know exactly which argument, or so write again. :)

Jeerze,

Simon

For more information about logginfile name and logging in vertx3 see: [Vertx3 Logging](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_logging)

Answer (score 2):

I configured Logback in Vert.x successfully, you can check the details in the following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43101501/973418

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning on adding slf4j, then just add the following dependency.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```